Calculating instantaneous stored energy in an inductor

Given the current through a $10 \,\text{H}$ inductor at $t = 25 \,\mu\text{s}$ is $5 \,\text{A}$ and that at $t = 0 \,\text{s}$ is $3 \,\text{A}$. Calculate the instantaneous stored energy in the $10 \,\text{H}$ inductor.”

The wording of this problem, specifically the word “instantaneous” is really throwing me off. According to my professor, the correct answer is $80 \,\text{J}$.
We know that the formula for energy stored in an inductor is $W = \frac{1}{2} Li^2$, so I simply calculated $W(25 \,\mu\text{s}) = \frac{1}{2}(10)(5)^2 = 125 \,\text{J}$.
However, my professor calculated the instantaneous energy using this formula, $W_L(t) = \frac{1}{2} L \left[ i^2(t) - i^2(t_0) \right]$ and substituting gives $W_L(25 \,\mu\text{s}) = \frac{1}{2} (10) \left[ (5)^2 - (3)^2 \right] = 80 \,\text{J}$.
I’m not the one with a Ph.D., but this just doesn’t sit right with me. How I’m interpreting “instantaneous stored energy” is the energy stored in the inductor at that particular moment, calculated using the current at that exact time. Only $125 \,\text{J}$ can be referred to as the instantaneous stored energy at $t = 25 \,\mu\text{s}$, whereas $80 \,\text{J}$ is the change in stored energy between two specific points in time. Am I wrong?

Is your professor proficient in English? I think you are correct; that is not instantaneous, but rather is the increment in instantaneous energy stored.

That question doesn’t seem right to me. Instantaneous energy needs to have a specific time identified, e.g. the instantaneous energy at t=25. I think they missed the word “change”. It should have been “Calculate the change in the instantaneous stored energy”

The instantaneous stored energy is the energy at a given instant in time. So the question, as worded, makes no sense.
The answer given by your professor, 80 J, is the change in stored energy from 0 to 25$\mu$s , not the instantaneous stored energy.
So you are not wrong.
Hope this helps.
